# How to save digits after decimal point in double number

Tags: java, format, decimal

Assume there is some class

```
public class Currency {

    private double value;

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Currency(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value + "";
    }
}
```

The point is:

There is float variable

```
double var = 10.000;
```

and object

```
Currency cur = new Currency(var);
```

I need that method toString() must return "10.000" just as var looks like(if there is sequence of zeros after decimal point suppose that it must return 3 zeros after decimal point), but it returns "10.0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format`:

```
    double a = 10;
    String s = String.format("%.3f", a);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Here is the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 0):

Once assigned to a double, the exact wording of the literal used to specify the value is lost, and just its value is retained.  If you need the exact formatting, you should represent it some other way (for example, as a string).  If you need a specific number of decimal places, then format your string to have that many.